# How to disable or turn off DHCPv6 on Cisco 3939B router?

Tags: dhcp-server

I am trying to set up a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials server properly.  I would assume it could also apply to non-Essentials also. i.e. Standard.

DHCP for BOTH IPv4 and IPv6 MUST be turned off or disabled on the router before setup of the server.  End server result should be Active Directory Domain Controller, DNS and DHCPv4 & DHCPv6 server.  NO DHCP on router.

IPv4 is not problem, but IPv6 is.  It doesn't appear to be just a matter of unchecking or checking a button to disable IPv6 like you can SIMPLY do with IPv4.

Without going into the already "overly" complicated realm of IPv6 and DHCPv6, and to please explain as "simply" as possible, what is the "standard" and proper INITIAL procedure to accomplish this important part of the process?

I am not really grasping all this "Stateful", "Stateless", "RA", "auto config", "m flag" and "o flag" stuff.  Honestly it is quite confusing and not quite straightforward like Ipv4 etc.

Thank you.

Comment: You do not _want_ to disable DHCPv6 on the cable modem unless the ISP has explicitly given you a static IPv6 prefix (and they most likely have not). You will need it enabled, in order to distribute the delegated IPv6 subnets into your network. You will have to make your domain controllers deal with this (and since I'm a Linux admin I can't really help you there).

Comment: Ok.  I was kind of getting that feeling but wasn't sure.  Thank you.  I know you are Linux, but maybe some one else can help.  If I let the router do DHCPv6 then, do I need to disable it on the windows server? Not sure the proper procedure here and stuck.  I know to disable DHCPv4 on router and create scope on server.  I just thought IPv6 MUST also be disabled on router like IPv4. Thank you.